# Google Sites Horizontal Navigation Bar Contents

Tags: google-classic-sites

Is there any way that the items in the Horizontal Navigation Bar can be copied between sites.  I am a primary teacher and the 30 pupils in my class each have a site.  These sites have been up and running for the past year.  We would like to add some Urls to the Horizontal Nav Bar and some of these would have drop down links also.  Is there any way that they can be copied if an original was created.

Answer (score 1):

Sites uses the pages that already exist in your Sites structure to build out the nav bar. This means that your 30+ sites, each with their own structure, cannot share/copy nav links between each other.

What you can do is add pages by URL. All you need to to is go to

`More` > `Edit Site Layout` > Click on the `horizontal nav bar` > Configure your pages > `Add URL`

When you add a custom URL to the nav, you can edit the text and paste the URL. Once you set this up, you can use the arrows above to manipulate the order of the pages. Clicking the right arrow will create a subpage (a page in the drop down)

This will allow you to at least only create 1 version of the new page and add it as a URL to all other existing site navigations.

[image]

**Remember:**

- This only works if the pages you want to add exist somewhere else, and the users of the original site have access to view the added pages.
- To set up horizontal nav bars you need to have selected the `Horizontal navigation` button when you first enter `Edit Site Layout`